# Deserialize HttpCookie object from JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

For some reason HttpCookie object fails deserialization from JSON. I get this error -

> Cannot populate list type System.Web.HttpValueCollection. Path 'Values', line .., position ..

I managed to deserialize the JSON into a custom class (`HttpCookieModel`) that doesn't have the `Values` property, and then rebuild the HttpCookie from the data.
But isn't there a simpler way?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; //  v7.0.1

public JsonResult GetCookie() {
     return Json(new { Success = true, Username = model.UserName, Cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true) });   
}

private static void DoSomeTests()
{
      // HttpWebRequest request....
      // Call GetCookie()
      // ...
      var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
      using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), true))
      {
           res = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
      }
      // Deserialize
      try
      {
           MyResponse mr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResponse>(res);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          string message = ex.Message;   // message: Cannot populate list type System.Web.HttpValueCollection. Path 'Values'....
      }


    public class MyResponse 
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
       // public HttpCookie Cookie { get; set; } // Problems deserializing Values collection.
        public HttpCookieModel Cookie { get; set; }
    }

   // This model works - but is there a simpler way?
    public class HttpCookieModel
    {
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
        public bool HasKeys { get; set; }
        public bool HttpOnly { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public bool Secure { get; set; }
        public bool Shareable { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public HttpCookie ConvertToHttpCookie()
        {
            HttpCookie result           = new HttpCookie(this.Name);
            result.Domain               = this.Domain;
            result.Expires              = this.Expires;
            result.HttpOnly             = this.HttpOnly;
            result.Path                 = this.Path;
            result.Secure               = this.Secure;
            result.Shareable            = this.Shareable;
            result.Value                = this.Value;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the json response and import it here http://json2csharp.com/ this will create the necessary classes needed for proper deserialisation, then just deserialise to the RootObject class (RootObject is the default name that json2csharp gives, change it to whatever suits your needs

Comment: I have already created this class - but it's the solution that I don't want to use. HttpCookie is a C# class, not a custom class, but DeserializeObject can't deserialize that and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try [MissingMemberHandling.Ignore](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MissingMemberHandling.htm):

Example usage:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(jsonResponse, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

With your code:

```
public class MyResponse 
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public HttpCookie Cookie { get; set; } //use HttpCookie as normal
    }
```

Apply `MissingMemberHandling.Ignore`:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
 jsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
 MyResponse mr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResponse>(res, jsonSerializerSettings);
```